# Dagger singleton creating new instance every time

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

**I have a module as follows.**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final Application app;

    public AppModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Architecture.ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides //scope is not necessary for parameters stored within the module
    public Context context() {
        return provideContext();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Application provideApp() {
        return app;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    SoundsRepository provideSoundsRepository(Context context, SoundsDAO soundsDAO) {
        return new SoundsRepository(context, soundsDAO);
    }
}
```

**A component like this.**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(Global global);

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);


    @Architecture.ApplicationContext
    Context getContext();

    Application getApplication();

    void inject(PostView postView);

    void inject(MediaPlayerService mediaPlayerService);
}
```

**In activity, fragment or service, I do this**

```
@Inject
    SoundsRepository soundsRepository;

@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
    //....
    ((Global) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
}
```

**In SoundsRepository**

```
@Singleton
public class SoundsRepository {
    @Inject
    public SoundsRepository(Context context, SoundsDAO soundsDAO) {
        this.context = context;
        this.soundsDAO = soundsDAO;
        System.out.println(TAG + "INIT");
    }
    // ....

}
```

So, now, every time I start to access an activity or service where **SoundsRepository** is injected, I get a new instance, I mean, the constructor of "SoundsRepository" fires again.

**What am I doing wrong?**

EDIT : Inject in Application Class

```
public class Global extends MultiDexApplication {

    protected AppComponent appComponent;
    private boolean calledAlready = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) return;
        //LeakCanary.install(this);
        initFirebasePersistance();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        FrescoUtil.init(getApplicationContext());
    }


    public AppComponent getComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add how you're creating the application component? Meaning, how are you creating the component returned here: ``((Global) getApplication()).getComponent()``? And when are you destroying it...

Comment: @Relm, as @Fred asked, it's interesting how the implemnetation of `Global#getComponentI()` looks like.

Comment: @Fred see the new edit, also, I'm not destroying it anywhere? Didn't know I had to destroy it.

Comment: @azizbekian see edit.

Comment: Ok, yes I see the new edit, but we need more :P Basically I think you're missing a detail - what a dagger scope actually means. So I'm interested in seeing how and where you are creating the component. Is it in the application ``onCreate``? Is it every time? and so on. Also destroying is not really necessary. It's just to have all the info.

Comment: @Fred, ohhh, see the updated edit.

Comment: Damn... Everything looks good. I need another minute here :|

Comment: Man I don't know. Everything seems ok. You're creating the component on application create and you keep it until the application is actually destroyed. This means that everything scoped with singleton should stay a singleton inside of each app run. Maybe double check that you're not seeing a log from a previous app run. Also, put a log or something on the provider method. You might accidentally be calling ``new SoundsRepository()`` somewhere else outside of dagger.

Comment: @Fred, yep its weird, checked the `SoundsRepository` class, its only included in the app module, and as for logging `provideSoundsRepository()`, I did, logs every time I open an activity where `SoundsRepository` is injected, even on resume.

Comment: I'd try removing the inject annotation from the constructor, since clearly you're not using constructor injection and see if that fixes it, since that would explain the issue. Also you should think about switching to proper constructor injection and removing the provides method from your module, adding the scope to the top of the class.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, removed `@Inject`, still not a singleton, also, can you give an example about a proper constructor injector for this?

Comment: David's suggestion is worth a shot. (Did you annotate `SoundsRepository` with `@Singleton`? 
Also consider adding a log statement in the module provider method for `SoundsRepository` to see if it is even being executed at all.

Also - you have 2 provider methods for `Context`, one of which is unqualified (I'm surprised it works). Why do you need the unqualified method? can you just remove it? instead you can just add the qualifier to the `Context` in the constructor of `SoundsRepository`.

Comment: @benji which Context method is unqualified?

Comment: @benji, yes, `SoundsRepository` is annotated with `@Singleton`

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that setup on github? I see nothing that would make the constructor to be called each time.

Comment: I'll agree that everything you've posted here looks fine, other than `provideSoundsRepository`, which is unnecessary since your implementation looks and acts exactly as Dagger would infer from your constructor (as long as the SoundsRepository class itself is marked `@Singleton`). Without seeing your actual repository, the best we can do is recreate it from your samples here and watch that work.

Comment: Hope you can share your project on github, currently I see nothing can make `SoundsRepository` constructor call twice

Comment: Libraries like LeakCanary will create their own process, creating a second application, creating a second component, creating a second SoundRepository. So multiple instances per se would be an expected behavior, but you should always end up with the same instance if you create multiple activities. Could you add how you see that there are different repositories created, or make sure that you actually receive different repositories when creating 2 different activities? It seems to me you might just be confused by multiple calls to the constructor.

Comment: Try to add singleton scope to this methods ```
@Provides
    @Architecture.ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides //scope is not necessary for parameters stored within the module
    public Context context() {
        return provideContext();
    }
```

Comment: Also what is the scope of SoundsDAO?

Answer (score 5):

1. In your module you have a method that provides an instance of SoundsRepository - good
2. In your AppComponent you are missing a:

   ```
   SoundsRepository soundsRepository();
   ```
3. In your `Global` which extends Application/MultidexApplication you create your DaggerAppComponent - good
4. In your other activities/fragments/services just call:

   ```
   Global application = (Global) getApplication();
   SoundsRepository sr = application.getComponent().soundsRepository()
   ```

Android guarantees you have only one instance of your Application (Global) class for all other actvities/services (its somewhat like a singleton).

**So keep your component in that application class, and whenever you need your class, call:** `(YourApplication) getApplication().getComponent().yourSingleInstanceSomething();`

I created and tested sample code for you: https://github.com/zakrzak/StackDaggerTest

Dagger's @Singleton is just a scope, and does not guarantee returning a singular instance of a class.

In my understanding, if you:

```
void inject(PostView postView);
```

you tell Dagger to make everything you annotated with @Provided in AppModule accessible in your PostView as soon as you request it with:

```
@Inject
SoundsRepository soundsRepository;
```

then dagger just calls the @provided method which in your case returns a new SoundRepository instance:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
SoundsRepository provideSoundsRepository(Context ........) {
    return new SoundsRepository(...);
}
```

which causes your problem